# Communication between Adapter of one Activity and another Activity

Tags: android

I have one adapter consisting of empty imageViews. There is a camera button, which opens up the camera to take a photo and view the photo in another activity. Upon saving this activity, the image must go back to the underlying activity and must save in the adapter in the exact position.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: you are storing images in local phone directory?

Comment: try to use fragments

Comment: Yes, I'm storing it in the local phone directory. But I don't know how to populate the recycler view after the image has been accepted.